# Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - Android 4.3?

Tags: android, adb

When connecting my Nexus 7 (2012) to the PC I get the
"adb connection Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
error very often since I upgraded to Android 4.3. Windows reports unknown USB device.
My HTC phone is always dedected correctly.

DDMS reset adb or reboot Nexus or reboot PC does not help.

It works once and than fails for dozens of retries.

The error happens a lot less when the Nexus is connected as a camera.
This also applies to new Nexus 7 (2013) devices.

I cannot reproduce this behavior on other PCs.

thank you very much

Comment: Not clear if it could be the issue, but are your dev tools new enough to support authenticated ADB?

Answer (score -1):

1)Check the device status, it should be 'device'
issue the following command  adb devices

It should show like this:

List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   offline
   device

2)if the same error occurs, print and see the logcat.
  use adb commands  like logcat , bugreport
  http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

3) before that you can try with rebooting the connected device from adb command shell.

4)try debugging with Nexus 7 adb tool kit